# Simple TeXmaker keyboard shortcuts messed up after upgrade (14.04-14.10)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, settings, latex

Whenever creating a document and pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> will produce the document's quick build and will immediately open a new window with the pdf view.

After the upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10 when pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> (even though the shortcut is still created within the settings menu) TeXmaker won't do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same issue. I installed the 4.4.1 deb package for ubuntu 14.10 from the Texmaker website which resolved the issue for me (http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux)